# Firefox throws security error 1000 on this simple enumeration

Tags: javascript, firefox, cross-browser, enumeration

I'll make it short:
I want to enum all available functions and objects inside of `window` object for creating some kind of object reflection code. 
it runs just fine in every browser but in Firefox.
here is my pseudo loop code:

```
var all_names=[];
for (var i in window)
{
    //if it's NOT an object
    all_name.push(i.toString());
    //if it's an object        
    enum up to 3 more levels in child objects.
}
```

And I don't want to use available APIs in Firefox such as `getOwnPropertyNames`.
So, what should I do? is there any better solution for enumeration in Javascript (cross-browser of course)

---

Here is some more technical info:

**Exact Firefox error:**

`[20:48:04.539] uncaught exception: [Exception... "Security error"  code: "1000" nsresult: "0x805303e8 (NS_ERROR_DOM_SECURITY_ERR)"  location: "http://localhost/test/common.js Line: 53"]`
**Exact enum loop code:**

```
function reflectAsString() {
    try{
        var m1 = "";
        var m2 = "";
        var m3 = "";
        for (var i in window) {
            if(window[i] && window[i]!= null && window[i] != "globalStorage")
                {
                m1 += i;
                first_instance = window[i];
                if(typeof first_instance == "object")
                    {
                    for(var j in first_instance)
                    {
                        if(first_instance[j] && first_instance[j]!= null)
                            {
                            m2 += j;
                            second_instance = first_instance[j];
                            if(typeof second_instance == "object")
                                {
                                for (var k in second_instance)
                                {
                                    if(second_instance[k] && second_instance[k]!= null)
                                        {
                                        m3 += k;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return hex_md5(hex_md5(m1)+hex_md5(m2)+hex_md5(m3));
    } catch(e) {
        try {
            var strToHash = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window).filter(function(property) {
                return typeof window[property] == 'function';
            });
            return hex_md5(strToHash.toString());
        } catch(e2) {
            return "undef";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to figure out *which* property under window et al is causing this error.  Doing so should provide enough info to either solve the problem or work around it.

Comment: @KirkWoll I think it's globalStorage which is deprecated and accessing it like this will trigger such errors, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done something similar by opening an iframe on the page I am interested in, and comparing the globals in the iframe's window with those in the parent window.
The try block will return the property name with an error flag, if there are any errors.

HTML for iframe src:

```
<html lang= "en">
<head>
<meta charset= "utf-8">
<title>Get Globals</title>
<style>
p{border:none;font-size:1.25em;font-weight:600;}
h2{color:navy;border-top:3px ridge navy;margin:1ex 0;}
span{margin:0 1em;}
</style>
<script>
navigator.sayswho= (function(){
    var N= navigator.appName, ua= navigator.userAgent, tem,
    ie= navigator.IEmod,
    M= ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie)\/?\s*([\d\.]+)/i);
    if(M && (tem= ua.match(/version\/([\.\d]+)/i))!= null) M[2]= tem[1];
    M= M? [M[1], M[2]]:[N, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
    if(ie && ie!= M[1]) M[2]= 'ie mode:'+navigator.IEmod;
    return M.join(' ');
})();
window.onload= function(){
    if(this!= top){
        var G={
            getInterface:1, InstallTrigger:1
        },
        B= [], C= [], k= ['HTML elements:'], d= navigator.sayswho || '',
        t= document.getElementsByTagName('p');
        for(var p in this) G[p]= 1;
        for(var key in top){
            try{
                if(!(key in G)){
                    if(top[key].nodeType== 1) k.push(key);
                    else B.push(key);
                }
                else C.push(key);
            }
            catch(er){
                B.push('error with '+key);
            }
        }
        if(k.length>1) B.push(k.join(' '));
        if(d) document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML+= d;
        t[0].innerHTML= B.join('<br>');
        t[1].innerHTML= C.sort().join(', ');
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Globals<span>in</span></h1>
<h2>New globals defined in the top window</h2>
<p></p>
<h2>Common window properties</h2>
<p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I found what I was needed in your codes, thanks. very helpful.